# What are the "complex legal concerns" negated by Ubuntu Advantage?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I am looking at the benefits of subscribing to Ubuntu Advantage and I have noticed the following line in the list of benefits to being a Ubuntu Advantage subscriber:

> Legal coverage: IP indemnification coverage so you can easily deploy Ubuntu in your business without complex legal concerns

What exactly are the complex legal concerns that are negated by Ubuntu Advantage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "IP" here means: intellectual property. I'm not lawyer but given the context:

> We take care of intellectual property (IP) infringement legal claims brought against customers in their use of Ubuntu.

Continue reading:

> Throughout the open-source world, all possible care is taken to respect intellectual property rights. In the unlikely event of an intellectual property issue in Ubuntu, Canonical will replace or modify the infringing portion of the software so that it becomes non-infringing, or obtain the rights for you to continue using the software.

If for some reason you get a claim for using any package/software that comes with the usage of Ubuntu, they will replace that piece of software and assume all the costs/damages that the claim could cause:

> In order to allow our support customers to deploy Ubuntu without complicated legal concerns, **Canonical will assume the legal defence, pay all legal defence costs, and pay any resulting damages judgement or settlement, for any claim brought against our support customers worldwide** by any third party for alleged infringement of patents, copyrights, trademarks, or trade secrets due to our support customer's use of the Ubuntu software during the term of their support services contract.

Reference:

- [Ubuntu Assurance | Ubuntu Advantage | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/ua-assurance-terms)

Comment: Well that's confusing™.

Comment: @Seth ehh... which part? And don't tell me "everything" (nor any synonym)

Comment: Just their legalese. Not your answer ;)